# How to get server date/time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have to get server date/time when clicking a button but don't know how to get from server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're handling the button's click event on the server then you can just call `DateTime.Now` and it will return the server's time (since the code is executed on the server).

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Good point - I guess it will just return the original time it loaded.

Comment: No; it would create invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' STANDARD TIME example:
    Body.Attributes.Add("onload", "displayDate('" & Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss tt") & "');")

    ' MILITARY TIME example:
    Body.Attributes.Add("onload", "displayDate('" & Format(Now(), "HH:mm:ss") & "');")
End Sub
```

I assumed VB as you have not specified a language you're using. you can use it in your button click event with other languages like C# too. **Note that my `<body>` tag has `id="Body"` and `runat="server"`**